# Joomla with Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, xampp

I've installed Xampp, and used phpMyadmin to create a database, I want now to use that with a Page made by Joomla,so I installed it with bitnami package, but I can't activate both, Xampp servers and Joomla at the same time, so when I try to log in phpMyAdmin of Joomla it doesn't recognise my admin and pasword of xampp. Any idea of how to solve the problem?

EDIT: I'm using Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIP: Don't use bitnami. Use Joomla as it is instead.
It will be much better for you on the long run.

So:

1. Uninstall Bitnami
2. Restart Apache & MySQL

Example:
[image]

3. Create a database in phpMYAdmin

Example:
[image]

4. Download Joomla
5. Extract Joomla's ZIP file into `C:\xampp\htdocs` in Windows or `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` on OSX.
   I would recommend creating a folder inside "htdocs" like "mysite" so you can add multiple sites in the future inside different folder's
6. Navigate to either `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/mysite` and follow the Joomla Installation Process

Comment: Can't I run the php file on the browser without a server?

Comment: Well, then how would your browser interpret php then?

From wikipedia: `PHP code is usually processed by a PHP interpreter, which is usually implemented as a web server's native module or a Common Gateway Interface (CGI) executable.`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to solve your problem.

1. Uninstall the bitnami package
2. Start your Xampp Apache and MySQL Server
3. Create a Database over phpMyAdmin
4. Download: https://www.joomla.org/download.html
5. Extract the files in the ZIP to your xampp installation in the folder `htdocs`. When you used the standard installation it is`C:\xampp\htdocs`
6. Open your browser on http://localhost and follow the installation instructions of Joomla